# InDesign Server - Can't resize image - it is locked and can't unlock it

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign, indesign-server

I am writing some JS code to relink an image, then resize it to fit the containing object. Simplified version of code:

```
var image = (get image);
try {
  image.itemLink.relink(File(new_filename));
}
catch(e) {
  (log it);
}

var image = (find image again because after the relink it would otherwise cause error "Object no longer exists")

(work out new width, height, v offset, h offset);

try {
  if(image.locked) {
    lock_later = true;
    image.locked = false;
  }
}
catch(e) { }

// Resize and reposition image
image.geometricBounds = [(rectangle.geometricBounds[0] + h_offset) + "mm", (rectangle.geometricBounds[1] + w_offset) + "mm", (rectangle.geometricBounds[2] - h_offset) + "mm", (rectangle.geometricBounds[3] - w_offset) + "mm"];

// Lock the image again if it was locked before
if(lock_later) {
  image.locked = true;
}
```

With the try/catch block around the `if(image.locked)` block, the resize line throws the error "Image is locked" (because it fails to unlock it). Without the try/catch but keeping the `if(image.locked)` block, it throws the error "The property is not applicable in the current state." when trying to access `image.locked`.

So what "state" is my image in, and why is it not "applicable" even though the app is clearly using it to prevent me resizing it? How do I resize my image, given that this is an automated process and in production I won't have access to InDesign to edit it manually beforehand?

Comment: What type of object is `image`? I believe that in the code not shown you are alternating between the container (which can be locked and unlocked) and the actual image inside (which cannot). Usually one locks the *container* page item, not the graphic object 'inside' it.

Comment: The `image` variable is an `Image` object. According to the IDS docs, `locked` is a read/write boolean property on `Image` objects specifying whether the image is locked. I believe I can access the container item with `image.parent` - perhaps I can try unlocking that instead and seeing what happens?

Comment: Paint me surprised. My main work horse is CS4 and so I just checked for that version, and you cannot lock a graphic. But: starting from the next version you *can*. I don't know if locking or unlocking a container also modifies its contents. It seems the documentation is unclear on that as well.

Comment: Guess what? If I use `image.parent.locked` instead of `image.locked` it works fine. Re-post your comment as an answer and I will happily accept it and give you your bounty. Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated in Adobe's documentation, an image *container* -- the parent frame 'around' an image, which is a generic [SplineItem](http://jongware.mit.edu/idcs6js/pc_SplineItem.html) -- can be locked and unlocked by changing the read/write boolean property `locked`.

In InDesign CS4 and earlier, the `Graphic` Class did not have this property, but since InDesign CS5 onwards, the property `locked` also appears in there and in all of its derived classes. According to Adobe's [documentation](http://jongware.mit.edu/idcs6js/pc_Graphic.html#locked]) it is a *read/write* property. However, this appears to be **wrong**. Experimenting with CS6, I found the `locked` property of a graphic inside its parent frame only *reflects* the parent's state, and is in fact *read-only*.

In the InDesign user interface in CS4 and earlier, the menu item "Lock" is disabled when a graphic inside a frame is selected. In the user interface from CS5 and later, a locked item cannot be selected, so the menu item cannot be invoked.

The easiest workaround, given a handle to a graphic image, is to check and/or change the state through its parent:

```
image = app.activeDocument.allGraphics[0]; // a handle to the first graphic
image.parent.locked = false; // unlock it
```